# How to send html to C# SelfHost console application

Tags: c#, self-hosting

Using System.Web.Http.SelfHost etc. how can I send a html page to the browser?

Currently, in Google Chrome it comes through as text. I cannot find how to change the header to text/html, and I don't know whether that will fix it.

I've tried a number of variations of the attached without success.

The Episode data comes through to the browser in Google Chrome Browser OK as Json, but in IE it asks whether I want to (O)pen or (S)ave it. In IE, the html has the same result.

I want to send the html from RAM, not disk.

Error-handling is omitted for brevity.

Code as follows :-

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.SelfHost;

namespace Console015
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpSelfHostServer server = null;

            using (StreamReader reader01 = new StreamReader("test01.html"))
            {
                LoginController.sPage = reader01.ReadToEnd();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(LoginController.sPage);

            String sUrl = "http://localhost:8080";
            var serverConfig = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(sUrl);
            serverConfig.Formatters.Clear();
            serverConfig.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
            serverConfig.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApiRoute",
                routeTemplate: "endpoints/{controller}",
                defaults: null
                );

            server = new HttpSelfHostServer(serverConfig);

            server.OpenAsync().Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Listening At : " + sUrl + "/endpoints/episode");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class LoginController : ApiController
    {
        public static string sPage = string.Empty;
        public HttpResponseMessage GetLoginPage()
        {
            // Create a 200 response.
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(sPage)
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Returning Login Page");

            return response;

        }
    }

    public class Episode
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ReleasedOn { get; set; }
    }

    public class EpisodeController : ApiController
    {
        public IList<Episode> GetAllEpisodes()
        {
            return new List<Episode>
            {
                new Episode {Id = 1, Name = "Episode 1", ReleasedOn =     DateTime.Now.AddDays(10).ToShortDateString()},
                new Episode {Id = 2, Name = "Episode 2", ReleasedOn =     DateTime.Now.AddDays( -5 ).ToShortDateString()},  
                new Episode {Id = 3, Name = "Episode 3", ReleasedOn = DateTime.Now.AddDays( -3 ).ToShortDateString()},  
                new Episode {Id = 4, Name = null, ReleasedOn = DateTime.Now.AddDays( 0 ).ToShortDateString()},  
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The HTML test data is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h1>My First Heading</h1>

    <p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be :
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "text/html";